# Can't add extension to file in QFileDialog

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt4, qfiledialog

I've got a problem with saving file with extension (get path to file and append extension) in PyQt4 with QFileDialog. My Python code looks like that:

```
dialog = QtGui.QFileDialog()
dialog.setDefaultSuffix(".json")
file = dialog.getSaveFileName(None, "Title", "", "JSON (.json)")
```

It works, path is correct, dialog title and filter are in dialog window, but second line was ignored. File doesn't have any extension.

How to add extension by default? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Try: `dialog.setDefaultSuffix("json")`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Calling `setDefaultSuffix` on an instance of `QFileDialog` has no effect when you use the [static functions](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qfiledialog.html#static-public-members). Those functions will create their own internal file-dialog, and so the only options that can be set on it are whatever is made available via the arguments.

Of course, `setDefaultSuffix` will work if the instance of `QFileDialog` is shown directly:

```
dialog = QtGui.QFileDialog()
dialog.setFilter(dialog.filter() | QtCore.QDir.Hidden)
dialog.setDefaultSuffix('json')
dialog.setAcceptMode(QtGui.QFileDialog.AcceptSave)
dialog.setNameFilters(['JSON (*.json)'])
if dialog.exec_() == QtGui.QDialog.Accepted:
    print(dialog.selectedFiles())
else:
    print('Cancelled')
```

But note that you cannot get a native file-dialog using this method.

If the file-name filters are specified correctly (see above, and 
[Barmak Shemirani's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29835741/984421)), the native file-dialog may provide a means of automatically selecting the filename extension (this is certainly the case with KDE on Linux, but I don't know about other platforms).

Answer (score 4):

Try with `*.json` instead of `.json`

```
file = dialog.getSaveFileName(None, "Title", "", "JSON (*.json)");
```