# Pyside2: How to use a QFileDialog to save files with specific extensions?

Tags: python, file, user-interface, pyqt, pyside2

I am trying to make a program that can dump retrieved data to a csv, html, etc. I know how to create QFileDialog, but when I use it, while it shows the file filters, it doesn't actually return the selected file filter to the program. Here is my code:

```
file_dialog = QFileDialog()
save_file_path = file_dialog.getSaveFileName(self, "Dump content", "", "HTML (*.html);; CSV (*.csv);;TXT (*.txt);;JSON (*.json);;SQL (*.Sql)")
print(save_file_path)
```

This is my output:

```
('/run/user/1000/doc/22efd139/1234file', '')
```

It gets the file name, but there is no extension included in the output. How can I get this to work?

Comment: it seems like a similar question [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29835413/cant-add-extension-to-file-in-qfiledialog)

Comment: I tried that, but it unfortunately didn't work

Comment: Hello! Any luck? It might be worth changing the example so that the getSaveFileName is used as a class method, no instantiation, only a `QFileDialog.getSaveFileName("Dump content", ...)` call perhaps. I can't right now check if that makes a difference, but I am partial to believe that to be the intended use.